# Array of `Option<T>` to `Option` array

Tags: rust

I'm trying to work with fixed-size arrays. I want to transform an array of `Option` values `[Option<T>; N]` to an `Option<[T ; N]>` such that I get `Some` if all entries are `Some`, but `None` otherwise.

Rust typically uses iterators to transform collections, but these do not have length guarantees.

This shoulld be legal, as the result if present must be the same length as the argument, but is there a way to do this whilst preserving the compile-time length guarantees, without using `unwrap` or similar?

Comment: @cafce25 I don't know if this is rude, but it's definitely disallowed and you should roll such edit back. However, I'm not sure this edit falls into this category, as in the original post they said to not use `unwrap()` and this may be considered the same. Anyway, if you encapsulate the `unwrap()` in a function that will never fail I think this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nightly, using [`try_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.try_map) (maybe there is a crate that supports that on stable, I don't know):

```rust
#![feature(array_try_map)]

pub fn convert<T, const N: usize>(arr: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<[T; N]> {
    arr.try_map(|v| v)
}
```

On stable, allocating:

```rust
pub fn convert<T, const N: usize>(arr: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<[T; N]> {
    let arr = arr.into_iter().collect::<Option<Vec<T>>>()?;
    Some(
        arr.try_into()
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("the array is of size {N}")),
    )
}
```

On stable, non-allocating, but requires `Default` and may be little inefficient:

```rust
pub fn convert<T: Default, const N: usize>(arr: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<[T; N]> {
    let mut result = [(); N].map(|()| T::default());
    for (item, result_item) in std::iter::zip(arr, &mut result) {
        *result_item = item?;
    }
    Some(result)
}
```

On stable, non-allocating, using unsafe. Should be last resort. The following code is subtly incorrect as it does not drop elements in case of `None` in the middle, which just demonstrates how hard it is to write correct unsafe code:

```rust
use std::mem::{ManuallyDrop, MaybeUninit};

pub fn convert<T, const N: usize>(arr: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<[T; N]> {
    let arr = ManuallyDrop::new(arr);
    let mut result_arr = MaybeUninit::<[T; N]>::uninit();
    for (i, item) in arr.iter().enumerate() {
        // SAFETY: This is in bounds, and wrapped in `ManuallyDrop` so not double drop.
        unsafe {
            result_arr
                .as_mut_ptr()
                .cast::<T>()
                .add(i)
                .write(std::ptr::read(item)?);
        }
    }
    // SAFETY: We initialized it above.
    Some(unsafe { result_arr.assume_init() })
}
```

Comment: Besides for `try_map`, all of those use potentially error-throwing functions and push the correctness burden on you. Even though the library function may well be doing the same thing, I would assume it is written to a certain standard, as well as benefitting from a certain amount of battle-testing in the field.

Comment: @AriFordsham Besides the custom unsafe, all behave correctly in the presence of panic.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.collect()` into an `Option<Vec<T>>` and `.and_then(|v| v.try_into().ok())`:

```rust
fn convert<T, const N: usize>(a: [Option<T>; N]) -> Option<[T; N]> {
    a.into_iter().collect::<Option<Vec<_>>>().and_then(|a| a.try_into().ok())
}
```

Which is straight forward and safe but creates an intermediate `Vec` unfortunately since `T` and `Option<T>` have different sizes I don't think you can do any better.
Since an iterator over an array (`[T;N]`) always yields `N` items `a.try_into().ok()` will always result in a `Some`